# Regex separate digts and chars into groups

Tags: regex

I try to seperate any string into 2 groups, digits and chars and eliminate all whitespace between this 2 groups. And after the first digit chars are allowed.

The `(\D*)(\S+)` works so far well for me except for the whitespace after the 1 group of chars.

Here is [my regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CzsiBb/1/).

Comment: Try `^(.*\S)\s+(\S+)$`, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/CzsiBb/2).

Comment: You can exclude matching the space and the digits `([^\d\s]+)\s*(\S+)` https://regex101.com/r/kxe6tV/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird this is what I'm exactly looking for, ty sir!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yours works also but its not possible to remove the whitespaces ;) Ty anyway.

Comment: Your example was just not representative enough.

Comment: Ya, you are right. I should better explain that it need to work with and without whitespaces in the string, my bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could exclude matching the whitespace chars as well using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^\d\s]+` matching 1+ times any char except a whitespace char or a digit.

You can match optional whitespace chars using `\s*`

```
([^\d\s]+)\s*(\S+)
```

**Explanation**

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\d\s]+` Match 1+ chars except a digit or whitespace char
- `)` Close group
- `\s*` Match 0+ non whitespace chars
- `(\S+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ times a non whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kxe6tV/1)